# Use jQuery toggleClass() when image inside a span tag is clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I'm working on an ASP.NET MVC3 project using Razor. I'm trying to implement a simple image gallery. My images are inside span tags and when an image is clicked I want to toggle the class of the span tag only for the clicked image.

This is my code :

```
<span class="document-image-frame">
    @if (image != null) {
        <img src="file:\\105.3.2.2\upload\@image.Name" alt="docImg" />
    }
</span>
```

I tried this script for toggling :

```
$('.document-image-frame img').click(function () {
    $(this).toggleClass();
})
```

It's not working. I guess in this case `$(this)` is the image itself and not the span tag, but if I try `$('.document-image-frame').toggleClass();` I loose the style for all span tags when I want to toggle only the style of the span where the image is clicked.

This is the generated HTML :

```
<span class="document-image-frame">>
    <img src="file:\\105.3.2.2\upload\\10007\Desert.jpg" alt="docImg" />
</span>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
 $(this).parent().toggleClass();
```

Or this:

```
$(this).parent().toggleClass("document-image-frame");
```

and if it works , read this: http://api.jquery.com/parent/

Comment: There is a timeout period before he can accept answers. Also, what does the .toggleClass() without parameters do?

Comment: @Cherniv Everything is easy, you just have to know how to do it ;)

Comment: @Cherniv Ah, apparently it toggles all classnames it finds on the element. Could be handy :) +1